# How to show Image in Login page when user has not been authenticated in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, forms-authentication

I have an Image in my login page that I want to show all the time.

However, it is only shown when the user has been authenticated. I have proved this authenticating the user and loading again the login page after the ticket has been created.

If the user has not been authenticated it will show the red cross as if the image is not found.

I'm using forms authentication.

How to show the image regardless the user login status?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: are you using asp.net membership provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the below in the web.config

```
<location path="Images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The path should be the path of the image folder.